# iPod sync issue

Tags: ipod

I just upgraded my computer from Windows XP to Windows 7.  I upgraded my iPod and when I plug my iPod into my computer I get the message "iTunes Library.ITL cannot be read because it was created by a newer version of iTunes."  What needs to be done so I can sync it with the computer again?

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. just go to C:\Users(your username)\Music\iTunes and rename the file iTunes Library.itl to iTunes Library.OLD

..... than Open your iTunes, got to "Help" --> "Check For Update". Once you update iTunes, go back to "C:\Users(your username)\Music\iTunes" rename newly created "iTunes Library.itl" to "iTunes Library.NEW" and your old file, "iTunes Library.OLD" rename back to "iTunes Library.itl".

You will be able to open your iTunes and all Libraries with in.

Source: [WikiAnswers](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_I_fix_this_issue._ITunes_Library.itl_cannot_be_read_because_it_was_created_by_a_newer_version_of_iTunes)